# Matlab toolbox, same name function

Tags: matlab, toolbox

I installed the SPRT toolbox in matlab but can't use the pca() function because there's a function with the same name in Matlab and it has priority. Working on mac (intel).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I presume your question is how to change the priority? Or maybe you want to call this function explicitly, without changing the priority? Please be explicit about your question!

Comment: `pca` is not “in MATLAB”, it is part of the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox. You can change the order of the directories in MATLAB’s search path (`path`), the earlier ones have precedence over the latter ones. Just make your SPRT toolbox come before the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox in the search path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Either changing the order or calling it without changing priority would be fine. I checked the order and the SPRT toolbox shows up first in the path editor but it still calls the matlab function. I'll try reinstalling the toolbox or searching how to explicitly  call it without changing.

Comment: It should not call the function named `pca` that it finds first in the search path. Are you sure that the one in the SPRT toolbox is not an overload? I can't find this toolbox through Google. Could you provide a link to its documentation?

Comment: I got the toolbox from my teacher but you can check the documentation here: (https://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/cmp/software/stprtool/)

Comment: To double check that you have all the paths set and ordered properly to use the correct `pca()` you want, use the `which` function. e.g.,`which pca` then it will give you the path to the one that has priority and you can troubleshoot from there